# Camera Button Time of press

Tags: java, android

I am here today becaus I have a problem with my camera app.
What I would like to do is that if the user presses the button for less than a second, it only takes a photo, but if the user presses for longer than a second, then we start a video.
The problem is that I can't find what to put in the "if" to know if the user presses for more or less than one second.
The problem is where there is "?????".
Thank you for your help
The code :

```
    captureImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (?????){
                    if (camera != null) {
                        try {
                            //prendre la photo

                            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallBack);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo prise", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            camera.startPreview();
                            mPictureCallBack = (Camera.PictureCallback) new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "/recorded.jpg");

                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "can't take photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
                // Là c'est quand t'appuies sur le bouton, tu mets ce que tu veux
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (??????){

                }


                // Là c'est quand tu relâches le bouton, tu mets ce que tu veux
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

[Picture of code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lueIE.png)

Comment: Paste the text of the code rather than using images :-)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to handle this is to use OnClickListener + OnLongClickListener for your camera button, but if you want to stick with motion events you can try the following, which measures the time elapsed between the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events:

```
    long start = 0;   // initialize timer variable  
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {  
        start = System.currentTimeMillis(); // starts the timer running  
    }  
    
    // 
    
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000){
    
                // code to take photo
    
        }else(
        
                // code to start recording video
        
        }
```

Comment: I did that you say but the problem is that if i do a short or a long press, he always take a photo. He never take a video. Thanks you for help me.

My new code is above your answer

Answer (score 0):

I did that you say but the problem is that if i do a short or a long press, he always take a photo. He never take a video. Thanks you for help me.

My new code :

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            long start = 0;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (camera != null) {
                        try {
                            //prendre la photo

                            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallBack);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo prise", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            mPictureCallBack = (Camera.PictureCallback) new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "/recorded.jpg");

                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "can't take photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "start vidéo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```